# running a binary file in python2.7 on linux

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm having issues running a external program in python using Popen to pass multiple variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import shlex, subprocess

a = raw_input("Enter a number:")
b = raw_input("Enter a file:")
c = raw_input("Enter dir to search:")

subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh', "./catnum.bin", "-m",  a, "--remove",  "-o results.txt", b, c])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use call instead:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["cactnum.bin", "-m",a, "--remove",  "-o results.txt", b, c])
```

However per the comment of J.F. Sebastian

The real issue is `invalid/unnecessary /bin/sh call b) "-o results.txt"` should be written as `"-o", "results.txt"` (2 args) i.e., the correct call is: `subprocess.check_call(["./catnum.bin", "-m", a, "--remove", "-o", "results.txt", b, c]) if catnum.bin is executable`

Comment: @Lucas: `subprocess.call()` is just `subprocess.Popen().wait()` (you've mixed `subprocess` and `os` modules -- `Popen()` is not deprecated). The real issue is a) invalid/unnecessary `/bin/sh` call  b) `"-o results.txt"` should be written as `"-o", "results.txt"` (2 args) i.e., the correct call is: `subprocess.check_call(["./catnum.bin", "-m",  a, "--remove",  "-o", "results.txt", b, c])` if `catnum.bin` is executable